# History showing as the user changed the field, but the user doesn't have access to the field

Tags: apex, permissions, history-tracking

A Picklist field is changing for a specific user, where the user has no access to update the field on VF Page and by other means like data loader.
In the field history tracking it is showing as the user changed the field.

This user is a end user who doesn't have any technical knowledge to make such kind of change by any other means.

Comment: Do you have controllers/extensions which use `without sharing` or which entirely omit their sharing declaration?

Comment: Controller for this VF page is with Sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The system tracks all changes to a tracked field, even if the user did not directly update the value via the UI, mobile app, or API. Visualforce code ignores FLS, as do triggers, Apex Code, and Workflow Rules. An administrator could easily set up ways to update the field without the user being able to update, or even view, the field.

Comment: Could you please eloborate more on this what would be the best approach I can  take to identify the issue.

Comment: @Suresh You would need to catch it in the act. Turn on some debug logs for a given user, let them do whatever it is they do that causes the field to change, then read the logs to see how it was changed. As I said, it could have been a Flow, Process Builder, Workflow Rule, or Trigger. Not all updates will appear though, so this might be difficult to track down.